# How to make eclipse-plugin contain letters in MANIFEST.MF bundle version?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to make Bundle-Version contain letters in the first part?

For example:

```
Bundle-Version: 3.build.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  The Bundle-Version must be OSGi version compliant.  This means the version must be this:

```
major[.minor[.micro[.qualifier]]]
```

Major, minor and micro may only be digits.  Qualifier may be a string consisting of alpha-numeric characters or an underscore.  A missing minor or micro component is interpreted as a 0.

You can read all the details on the [OSGI Vrersion JavaDoc](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/Version.html) page.

Comment: The thing is I already know this but I was trying to add Tycho for eclipse-plugins and in our company the poms have a version of the style `3.build.1` whereas the bundle-version is set to `1.0.0` and Tycho si complaining that the 2 versions must match and I can't modify the version in the pom (it is generated automatically for each version).

Comment: Well unfortunately, the maven version that your company uses is not OSGi compliant.  Best I can think of is to run a script before the tycho-versions:update-pom phase to translate the version to an OSGi compliant version.  Problem, of course is that you will have different versions for your OSGi bundles as you will have for your maven artifacts.  I'm not entirely experienced with tycho, but something like this could work.

Comment: Do you have an example? I think I saw one before who copied all his projects to change the pom versions but couldn't find it

Comment: No example, but after looking into this a little more, tycho-versions:update-pom is probably what you want.  Keep the canonical OSGi version in your manifest and run the goal. See more here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html#maventycho_generatingpom

Comment: For your info, I found a nice example without using any extra plugins http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html